# How can I track my visa application through VFS when the status shown hasn't updated for ten days and I've not had an SMS recently?

Tags: application-status, vfs-global

I applied for a Business visa on 10th October and opted for SMS Facility in Delhi. First day I got an SMS from VFS Team stating application forwarded to Embassy. Today is the tenth working day and I have not received any further updated SMS from VFS Team about the application status.

Is there any way I can track the status of my application?

Comment: What country's visa did you apply for?

Answer (score 3):

VFS, in case all 3rd party visa processing firms, are crap in terms of updating the current status of your visa application. The only have 2 status, application send to embassy and application processed and received back from embassy. In between those 2 statuses they will not and cannot give any updates.

Firstly the embassies doesn't update them about the ongoing processes, as it involves work with no apparent gain, other than putting the visa applier at ease. I would try calling the embassy with the reference number to get an update. If you get across a good soul he(she) may update you about the status. Done so in the past and have always managed to get an update on my application.