# Could I have approached South African Embassy without going through VFSGlobal for faster visa processing and news updates?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-africa, application-status

I just went through this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37698/visa-application-status-tracking) . Would it have been a good idea to visit the consul-general's office in Mumbai to apply for a short stay conference visa in South Africa or is vfsglobal the only option?

I am looking for better visa processing time and news updates and just realized that because I did it from Pune, it will take at least 7 working days to get [any idea about the status.](http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/allaboutyourvisas.html)

Also, I haven't been able find a website for the South African Consulate-General in Mumbai. Only different links with the telephone numbers, fax numbers and such info. Is there an official site I could look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VFS Global is the official agent for visa applications on behalf of [the High Commission of South Africa in India](https://southafricainindia.wordpress.com/) and the South African Consulate-General Mumbai. Accordingly, everything must go through VFS Global, and they would be the ones to update you on your application's status after the appropriate time has passed.

You seem very nervous about this process, a phenomenon one of our esteemed members likes to call "post-submission anxiety." Unfortunately, waiting is just one of those things that is part of getting a visa. You've submitted your application, and while it is understandable to be anxious about it, there is unfortunately nothing you can do until a response is ready but wait.

Many VFS facilities offer a range of premium services to accelerate the processing time and you should check to see what services (if any) are available to you.