# Irregular desposits and bank statements for short-term visa for South Africa

Tags: visas, south-africa, proof-of-funds, proof-provenance-of-funds, application-status

I saw this great [Q&A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and realized I parked funds unwittingly and shared that while doing my visa-application. The thing is, I am a freelancer and do both check and cash transactions with my clients. Whenever I have a size-able sum they go into term deposits of some bank or stocks or bonds or whatever generates the most return in due course of time.

Now about a couple of years back, I have bought a flat (under construction) and have been paying from a single bank account just in case I need to keep track of all the payments.

Now for the visa part, although it is under processing, should I have also added the explanations stating these funds are for a flat I booked ? There is just one more transaction which shows that some amount was given to a Company. What would have been the right way ?

I did share my last 6 months bank account statement instead of the 3 months they asked (from November '15 to May '16.) although not much activity therein.

Comment: Hi Shirish. As I mentioned in [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68968/could-i-have-approached-south-african-embassay-without-going-to-vfsglobal-for-fa), you clearly have some anxiety about your application. The thing is, you've already submitted it; it is now literally out of your hands for the next several days. If they have questions or reject you because of your finances, you can come back here and post what they say and ask for more advice on how to apply again.

Comment: I'll add that you have not "parked funds unwittingly," because all the funds are legitimately yours for travel purposes. The nature of your transactions might cause someone to think you have done so, because they aren't as obvious as regular salary payments, but that doesn't mean you've done anything wrong. The solution, which you would only need to undertake if your application is rejected, would be to provide more documentation and explanations to show the source of your deposits: check stubs from your clients, a brokerage statement showing transfers from your investment accounts, etc...

Comment: This appears to be post-submission anxiety at the flipping-out stage. There is nothing to be done until you receive a decision and see if it's a refusal or not.  Read http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/application-status/info